# Looking for a fairly simple 2D graphics library

Tags: c, graphics, embedded

Ideally, I want a library that is similar to the primitive Java2D or Quartz stuff - e.g. setFill, setStroke, moveToPoint, lineToPoint, quadCurveToPoint, fillPath, strokePath, etc.  Rotation and scaling of paths would be nice, but not essential.  Drawing strings with a proportional font would also be nice.  Open source, free as in speech, and free as in beer would be great!

This has to run on an embedded ARM7 with a small color LCD panel.  No hardware graphics support.  Memory very tight, 20 kbyte RAM and 256 kbyte flash.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366278/graphics-library-for-embedded-systems-without-linux

Comment: If running Linux kernel, look at: http://www.microxwin.com/

Comment: Also similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/595326/10396).   The suggestion there for [OpenGL-ES](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogl-es) looks reasonable.

Comment: Tight: less than 256K Flash available, less than 20K RAM available.  Question 366278 was useful.  I think maybe I'm looking at porting some drawing routines and cobbling together the library myself.  (The packages suggested mostly require a lot more memory than I've got available.)

Comment: With so little RAM and flash, especially if you want the flash for other things too, I would also look at other code mostly for inspiration and snippets of code. Going back to old-school game programming books from the DOS or Amiga/Atari era might also help.

Comment: Luckily(?), I'm old enough to have a bunch of paper books from the 80s and 90s on graphics programming.  I think I'll dig them out, blow off the dust, and look for some algorithms.  Thanks, everyone (and especially Amigable Clark Kant), for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SDL_draw](http://sdl-draw.sourceforge.net/). This library draws on an [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) surface, but you should be able to easily adapt it to draw on the screen of your embedded device. The license is GPL, not sure if that works for you.

Comment: SDL_draw looks promising - thanks.  Not sure about GPLv2 - I guess I'll have to ask the legal people.

Comment: SDL is pretty big if you ask me.

Comment: Did you really read my answer? The idea is to take SDL_draw, which is small, and port it to this embedded device. Never suggested using SDL. Maybe you should check out the SDL_draw source code, all the algorihms to draw lines, circles, flood fill, etc. are there. It would be easy to adapt to draw on something other than SDL.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [the Cairo graphics library](http://cairographics.org/) in an embedded device. We weren't too worried about memory though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it compares to where you come from, but allegro (mostly for games) is free, easy, and pretty well-supported:

http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/

Edit: I missed the embedded part. I doubt you want allegro then. Sorry.

Comment: Why not?  Is it embedded Linux?

Comment: No. I just thought you might want something optimized for it. If not, i'be used it a little and really liked its

Comment: ease of use and community support.

Answer (score 0):

openCV might be worth a look. It's more designed for manipulating and diagnosing images rather than to draw them yourself from scratch, but it's open-source, and fairly easy to use.

It's quite fast, so an extra point for embedded systems.

Comment: openCV is n image processing library - it's display stuff is not suitable for embedded or any performance application